# Generating different content when creating picture on different machines

Tags: php

I want to create a picture from a passed binary string:

```
$fileName = uniqid().".".$imgType;
$fileName = "../tmp/".$fileName;
$f = fopen($fileName,'wb');
$picture =  mb_convert_encoding($picture, "UUENCODE", "UTF-8");

fwrite($f, $picture);


fclose($f);
```

This works quite well on one machine with PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4. The picture is created properly. If try it on a different machine with PHP 5.3.19 the output is very strange. E.g. if you open the file with `less` then you will find `\0` instead of desired `^@` characters.

**Why does this happen?**

The binary string is part of a post request from a website using HTML5 Formdata encoded in both cases with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

```
$picture = convert_uudecode($picture);
```

Comment: Did not help. Neither `convert_uuencode/convert_uudecode` in several places. Solved it actually by transporting the picture encoded in bas64 and using `base64_decode` then. Et Voilá.